# How to get process name from the process id in Solaris

Tags: c, linux, unix, solaris

I wish to know is there any way (solaris api) for getting the process name from the given process id. In Linux there is way from using the /proc but I am not sure about Solaris.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks
Arpit

Answer (score 3):

Solaris has `/proc` as well, but it behaves somewhat differently.  The documentation for it is [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/816-5174/6mbb98ui2/index.html).   You probably want the `psinfo` stuff.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I could see that there is file psinfo exists in /proc/<pid>/ . Is there any solaris api which can extract the information.

Comment: You *need* to read the documentation I linked. There is a `struct` definition there which defines the contents of the `psinfo` file.